# Parser Error Message: The file '/Site1.Master' does not exist --- but it does

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, master-pages

Seems like an easy-to-fix error, but I've been banging my head on this for a while.  App works fine in the VS built-in webserver, but not after moving it to the dev server with IIS7.

The default.aspx file refers to the master page in the page directive...

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"      CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.Default" %>
```

Site1.Master is in the site's root directory, along with default.aspx.  The folder permissions are read to Everyone at this point.

This is an intranet site so IIS authorization is anonymous disabled, windows auth enabled, impersonation enabled.  App pool is .NET v4, managed pipeline integrated.

I've looked through this site and others for answers and while others have had the same problem, it was for different reasons.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not try by making it MasterPageFile="Site1.Master"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when we moved our site from one server to another. Our new site is on a VPS at a good hosting company (SoftSysHosting.com) and their tech support created a virtual directory of to where our website/app is. That solved it!

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this issue by removing the CodeFile="..." Option in the first line in the Site.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.Master.cs"     
inherits="CG.PresentationLayer.WA.MasterPage" %>
```

into:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="MyApp.MasterPage" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue before.  The underlying problem is that I assumed that the paths would stay the same and they did not.  Log into your dev server and navigate to your master page.  Open the page's properties in Explorer and view the path.  Now in a test page on your application run a HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath() and view where the app is running from.  From there you can see where the mismatch is taking place.

Comment: I had the same issue when we moved our site from one server to another. Our new site is on a VPS at a good hosting company (SoftSysHosting.com) and their tech support created a virtual directory of to where our website/app is. That solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose if you are having the root dir of your website or webapplication as given in the pic like "WebApplication1". This is your root folder of the site.
So just copy and paste the content inside the root folder "WebApplication1" to the "root folder" "/" of the FTP address.
**Not: dot not copy with root folder WebApplication1. 
just copy the content inside the root folder**.
Your Dir Structure
==+WebApplication1
====Properties
====Referance
====PropertiesSite1.Master
====Web.config
====Webform1.aspx